# How can I change a table's column widths?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a very large table that I need to include in a prototype. How do I change the column widths? My attempts using CSS have not worked.

http://jsbin.com/lebokewi/1/edit?html,css,output

***CSS***

```
table, th, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#colHdr th:nth-of-type(1) {width: 100px;}
#colHdr th:nth-of-type(2) {width: 50px;}
#colHdr th:nth-of-type(3) {width: 200px;}
#colHdr th:nth-of-type(4) {width: 60px;}
#colHdr th:nth-of-type(5) {width: 80px;}
```

Comment: Did you try: 
column-width:100px;
-moz-column-width:100px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-width:100px; /* Safari and Chrome */ ?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried all of these and they're not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. The table width needed to be defined.

```
table {
  width: 3000px;
}

table, th, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#colHdr td:nth-of-type(1) {width: 100px; color: green;}
#colHdr td:nth-of-type(2) {width: 250px; color:blue}
#colHdr td:nth-of-type(3) {width: 80px; color: orange}
#colHdr td:nth-of-type(4) {width: 175px; color: purple}
#colHdr td:nth-of-type(5) {width: 175px; color:red;}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Figuring out that the width was not defined solved my problem. This could defiantly help someone else who didn't realize they had to define a width property of a table.

Answer (score 1):

*Try using <col> width attribute:*
**Example**

```
<table>
    <col width="130">
    <col width="80">
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Reference**
[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_col_width.asp)

Comment: Yes, I did try this solution and it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you style directly in the html the th doesn't change the widths of all collumns?

Like so:

```
<th style="width:30%"></th>
```

Comment: I tried with less columns and without those full width cell in the middle and <th width="15%"></th> and it worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remove any columns or merged cells.

Comment: Actually I tried again with merged cells and seems to work for me :S You just have to try not to pass the 100% in total.

Answer (score 0):

Set your table-layout property like so:

```
table
{
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Then in your first row, define your widths:

```
<tr>
  <th width="5%">Hey</th><th width="95%">Hello, big row</th>
</tr>
```